# How to add multiple HTML elements with their properties in react array?

Tags: reactjs

I am adding HTML with class property in react array.
`colArray1.push( <div className={classes.imgContainer} key={875643}>);`
It can not renders and showing
"**Cannot read property 'imgContainer' of undefined**"
How to add multiple HTML elements with their properties in react array?

Comment: That's not question about `React`. All I can say your `classes` is undefined, try to debug it

Comment: can you share more snippet of your code, this will give us better understanding of what you're trying to achieve. Thanks

Comment: When it is compiled outside push, it runs. But when I try within push it fails.

Comment: I want 3 elements to be pushed in array and render them in table.colArray1.push(  <div className={classes.imgContainer} key={875643}>
                    <img src={product2} alt="..." className={classes.img} />
                  </div>)

Answer (score 0):

You could just make an array of strings and render the appropriate elements, using a simple mapping, like so:

```
const elements = [['div', classes.imgContainer], ['span', classes.otherContainer]];

return (
    elements.map(elem, i => {
        switch (elem[0]) {
            case 'div':
                return <div className={elem[1]} key={i} />
            case 'span':
                return <span className={elem[1]} key={i} />
            default:
                return <React.Fragment />
        }
    });
);
```

Comment: How to define HTML text in that?

Comment: just add it to the array elements, eg.`['div', classes.sth, 'The text I want rendered']`, and then just reference it within your returned html element as `elem[2]`